# Show Java Swing inputDialog on load

Tags: java, swing

I have a java GUI form in written in Swing, and I want to prompt a input dialog when the form is loaded. My approach was to put the prompt in the class's run method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new form_editStu().setVisible(true);

            promptUser();
        }
    });


   void promptUser()
   {
        JOptionPane.showinputDialog("Enter value:");
   }

}
```

Nothing happens. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code snippet you have posted, the `promptUser()` method should be inside the `Runnable`!

Other than that there are a number of typos (e.g., `JOptionPane` does not declare a method `show`**i**`nputDialog(String message)`.

I'd strongly suggest to start using an IDE, such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org), which can do some things for you automatically. When trying your code for example, it automatically placed the `promptUser()` method inside the `Runnable`.

E.g.,

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               ...
               promptUser();
            }

            private void promptUser() {
               JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value:");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I concur. Time for an IDE for you. Although I recommend Netbeans :) (https://netbeans.org/)

Comment: Sorry for the typos in the snippet. I am using an IDE (netbeans) in fact and the typos are there because I didn't directly copy/paste the code from it. And netbeans didn't suggest placing the method in the runnable either. Anyway I tried your suggestion and still the dialog isn't showing...

Comment: What does `new form_editStu().setVisible(true);` look like in the original code then?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry but I cant get code formatting working here!! I simply added the promptUser inside the runnable as you suggested. everything else is generated by the IDE.        

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new form_editStu().setVisible(true);
                promptUser();
            }
            
            private void promptUser()
            {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter SID: ");
            }
    
   
        });'

Comment: Please post the code to the `form_editStu()` class, and the console output. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: Also, if you comment out the line above the call to `promptUser()`, do you get the dialog?